# Command did not exit successfully aws cloudformation package --template template.yml exit status 255

Tags: amazon-web-services

The following command did not exit successfully:

```
aws cloudformation package \
    --template template.yml \
    --s3-bucket $S3_BUCKET \
    --output--template template-export.yml
```

exit status 255.

Comment: Please always include error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you have supplied both template options incorrectly.

To get help for an awscli command, you can run:

```
aws <service> <command> help
```

For example:

```
aws cloudformation package help
```

When you do this, you will see that the options for template files are:

```
--template-file <value>
--output-template-file <value>
```